# My symfony2 controller is not redirecting

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have created one defaultcontroller which is given below

```
namespace Mytest\VameBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
}

public function myactionAction($name)
{
    return new Response('<html><body>'.$name.'</body></html>');
}
```

}

The routing file is as look like bellow.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;


$collection = new RouteCollection();

$collection->add('name', new Route('/vame',array(
    '_controller' => 'MytestVameBundle:Default:index',
    )));

$collection->add('home', new Route('/vame/{name}',array(
    '_controller' => 'MytestVameBundle:Default:myaction',
    'name' => 'hhhhhhhhhh',
```

)));

```
return $collection;
```

It shows the following error

**The page isn't redirecting properly**

What i want to do is once the default controller is called with index action it will redirect to myaction Action with one argument.

so please any help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app redirects the request in a way that will never complete. So you have some kind of redirection loop.

It seems that your code is OK. However your should not hardcode parameters in the routing file but like this

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home', array('name' => 'test')));
```

Do you have more routing definitions? Maybe they interfere each other. Can you post your log?

Comment: Thank you i got my answer. i am not passing the parameter to the url.